# Which strategy can be used when converting back and forth between a domain class and several versions of the same target class?

Tags: c#, mapping

For my specific context I control the target classes. They were auto-generated based on XSDs and have huge overlaps because they represent different versions of the same class.
Each version is a huge C# class of over 5.000 lines.

Support can't be dropped for old versions. This means we always need to be able to map the domain class to several different versions and back again. There are always small but breaking changes from version to version. More than 90% of the target class is always the same, even if the code is duplicated for each version.

Currently there is one big mapping for each format, which is a horror. There is so. much. duplicated. code. Furthermore, developers tend to make updates where they need it, and skip everything else, which means individual versions often go out of sync, meaning that one version will be updated to do something that other versions don't. This is also not ideal.

So my question to you is: What strategy can you use for this kind of mapping?

Comment: Since it looks like I might not get an answer to this question, would the one downvoter mind sharing why my question is bad? Maybe I have overlooked something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with a solution that achieved the main targets:

- Decent compile-time safety to spot mapping errors
- De-duplication of code
- No messing with the auto-generated code

We did this by exploiting that the auto-generated classes are generated as partial. That means we can extend them.

We ended up creating hierarchies of interfaces/classes looking like this:

- ClassV1 implements IClassVerySpecificV1
- ClassV2 implements IClassVerySpecificV2
- IClassVerySpecificV1 implements SpecificA, SpecificB, SpecificC and IClassBasic
- IClassVerySpecificV1 implements SpecificB, SpecificC, SpecificD and IClassBasic

A mapper would then look like:

- ClassV1Mapper requires a SpecificAMapper, SpecificBMapper, SpecificCMapper and ClassBasicMapper
- ClassV2Mapper requires a SpecificBMapper, SpecificCMapper, SpecificDMapper and ClassBasicMapper

This way we could map 90% of everything by just throwing everything that belongs to IClassBasic into a ClassBasicMapper.

We did run into some issues however:

- As you can already guess, we end up with a LOT of interfaces. More than you want.
- Sometimes a field exists across versions, but has different (enum) values. Our domain model would have the superset, with an attribute specifiying which values were valid for which versions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of your classes, and having to maintain multiple versions, I'd suggest serializing and serializing.  Assuming that they otherwise approximate one another, `JsonConvert` doing `JsonConvert.Deserialize<TargetClass>(JsonConvert.Serialize(sourceClass))` should solve it, though I've not worked with such large models to have any idea on how performant it is.

Alternatively, you could use a t4 template (if you're not in .net Core anyway) to generate the mapping using reflection into a common method or whatever.

As far as preventing the Developer problem... Interfaces, base classes that define as much of this centrally as possible.  Code reviews to ensure that developers are making changes to the lowest layer they possibly can.

You can do some tricky things with inheretence with static `using` statements, I'm pretty sure.

Something dumb like

```
using OldVersion = path.to.the.class.CantRenameThis;

class CantRenameThis : OldVersion
```